# How do I email collaborators of a change I made in a shared Google document

Tags: google-docs

I used to be able to email collaborators when I made a change to a Google doc but that option is no longer available. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The "Email collaborators..." function is in the "File" menu.

[image: File menu]